# Confused selecting Info From Two DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have two database AgencyDB(primary DB) and AgencyBackupDB(Deleted Info from AgencyDB by user) and i have this two table in both DB(but there is no relationship in AgencyBackupDB between Tables).this is my question:
I want select all info from AgencyBackupDB in tables SabtHazine and info from related table Hazine.i want if HazineID from Hazine table Doesnt Exist in AgencyBackupDB select it From AgencyDB .
this is script of All Tabel With Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hazine](
    [HazineID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HazineGroupID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Mablagh] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HazineName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Hazine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HazineID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Hazine] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Hazine] ([HazineID], [HazineGroupID], [Mablagh], [HazineName]) VALUES (1, 1, 20000, N'صابون گل')
INSERT [dbo].[Hazine] ([HazineID], [HazineGroupID], [Mablagh], [HazineName]) VALUES (3, 2, 10000, N'بروس')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Hazine] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SabtHazine]    Script Date: 04/07/2013 17:34:59 ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SabtHazine](
    [SabtHazineID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HazineID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EndUserName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Tedad] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [sabtHazineDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Describtion] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SabtHazine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SabtHazineID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SabtHazine] ON
INSERT [dbo].[SabtHazine] ([SabtHazineID], [HazineID], [EndUserName], [Tedad], [sabtHazineDate], [Describtion]) VALUES (6, 3, N'SA', 3, CAST(0xC2360B00 AS Date), N'
')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SabtHazine] OFF
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_SabtHazine_Hazine]    Script Date: 04/07/2013 17:34:59 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SabtHazine]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SabtHazine_Hazine] FOREIGN KEY([HazineID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hazine] ([HazineID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SabtHazine] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SabtHazine_Hazine]
GO
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: Sounds like you want to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between databases and `COALESCE` the results.

Comment: i write this query but it give me this error:
**All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.**

    select SabtHazineID, SabtHazine.HazineID, EndUserNAme, Tedad, sabtHazineDate, Describtion from dbo.SabtHazine
    left JOIN    dbo.Hazine ON dbo.Hazine.HazineID = dbo.SabtHazine.HazineID 
    union all
    select Hazine.HazineName,Hazine.Mablagh from AgencyDB.dbo.Hazine
    where HazineID not in (select HazineID from dbo.Hazine)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the additional information.  It's difficult to find and to read when it is hidden in comments.

Comment: The error is telling you that when you UNION (ALL) two queries together, the number of columns in the query before the UNION must match the number of columns in the query after the UNION.  In your case, you have 6 columns UNION ALL 2 columns, which SQL Server cannot do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
 BsH.SabtHazineId,
 BsH.HazineID,
 BsH.EndUserNAme,
 BsH.Tedad, 
 BsH.sabtHazineDate, 
 BsH.Describtion,
  Coalesce( BH.HazineName, H.HazineName ) as [HazineName],
  Coalesce( BH.Mablagh, H.Mablagh ) as [Mablagh]
  from AgencyBackupDB.dbo.SabtHazine as BSH 
    left outer join    AgencyBackupDB.dbo.Hazine as BH on BH.HazineID = BSH.HazineID
    left outer join   dbo.Hazine as H on H.HazineID = BSH.HazineID
```

Answer (score 0):

This may point you in a better direction:

```
select BH.SabtHazineId, BH.HazineID, BH.EndUserNAme, BH.Tedad, BH.sabtHazineDate, BH.Describtion,
  Coalesce( BSH.HazineName, H.HazineName ) as [HazineName],
  Coalesce( BSH.Mablagh, H.Mablagh ) as [Mablagh]
  from AgencyBackupDB.dbo.SabtHazine as BSH left outer join
    AgencyBackupDB.dbo.Hazine as BH on BH.HazineID = BSH.HazineID left outer join
    dbo.Hazine as H on H.HazineID = BSH.HazineID
```

It joins the `Hazine` tables in both databases (assuming that you run it from the `AgencyDB` database) and uses `COALESCE` to pick a (hopefully) non-NULL value.